# Continue a bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash

After the success view of the host ( IPs ) I need to ping them in order to check if they are up. SIDS file contains 2 columns with hostnames. Are there any suggestions on how to Iimprove the code below?

```
#!/bin/bash
LINES=`cat /home/marko/SIDS | sed "s!/!-!g" | wc -l`

for (( i=1; i<=${LINES}; i++))
do
  FIRSTIP=CPE-`sed -n "${i}{p;q}" /home/marko/SIDS | awk '{print $1}'| sed "s!/!-!g"`
  SECONDIP=CPE-`sed -n "${i}{p;q}" /home/marko/SIDS | awk '{print $2}'| sed "s!/!-!g"`
  COUNT=$( host ${FIRSTIP} | grep address | wc -l )
  if [ $COUNT -gt 0 ]
  then
    echo success
  else
    echo ${SECONDIP}
  fi
done
```

Comment: How to print the IP`s from the host check and ping them.

Comment: The 2 columns are relative. If the host from the 1st one doesnt have ip it will check the second one. If the 1st one have IP it will continiue to the next line of the 1st column. How to include the sample input ?

Comment: Click on edit link below your question and provide sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `dig`, to avoid searching the output of `host`:

```
IP=$(dig +short $SERVERNAME)
```

Then to check, if the host is alive:

```
if ping -q -c $IP >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "OK"
fi
```